# Difference between using GeoServer as platform independent vs as a Service

Tags: geoserver, installation

I've been trying to install GeoServer into our servers which is Windows Server. I am curious about different types of installing. For example the documentation is stating that we are having a chance to install GeoServer either Platform Independent version or using Installer. Does it matter regarding the capabilities of the GeoServer ? I didn't see any adavantage or disadvantage documentation for setuping so.

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform independent binary uses a cut down version of jetty and requires you to start and stop it manually, where as installing as a service starts automatically when you start windows up. In neither case should you use jetty for a production server, where using tomcat and a web server (Apache or Nginx) will give much better control over performance and security.

Comment: I haven't understand clearly. So In my case using as server would be better for considering performance and security reasons right ?

Comment: No, tomcat as a service would be better